# MYSQL: Query to update an incremental value and store the returning value

Tags: mysql

I have a query to substract a value stored on the DB.

```
UPDATE tablename SET 
 available = IF( available > 0, available - " . $var . ", 0 ) , 
 purchases = purchases + 1 
 WHERE condition
```

Is posible to get the new value of field **available** without make a new SELECT and then penalize the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but I'm <strike>87,587%</strike> sure it works.

An update statement does not return a resultset, however you can set a @var variable and select from that.

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET  
  available = @fastpeek:= IF( available > 0, available - " . $var . ", 0 ) 
  ,purchases = purchases + 1 
WHERE condition
LIMIT 1;

SELECT @fastpeek as available_in_update;
```

This will break if you update more than 1 row however: when updating more than 1 row, @fastpeek will only show the last update. Hence the limit 1.
You still need an extra select, but it will not need to query the database, it will just retrieve the @var from memory.

Comment: Thanks Johan! I had to make a little tweak to your brilliant suggestion. Finally the query I used was: `UPDATE tablename 
SET 
  available=@fastpeek:=IF( available > 0, ...`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mysql user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION registerPurchase(idParam INT, qty INT) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE avail INT, purc INT,

    SELECT available, purchases INTO avail, purc FROM tablename WHERE id = idParam;

    SET avail = IF( avail > 0, avail - qty, 0 );
    SET purc = purc - 1;

    UPDATE tablename SET 
     available = avail, 
     purchases = purc
     WHERE id = idParam;

    RETURN avail;
END
```

Or something like that. You can call this using `SELECT registerPurchase(1234, 2);`, for example. This could be combined with @Johan's solution for even greater justice.

EDIT:

Here's a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html.

Comment: +1 That will perform even faster, because you save an extra call to the DB